# Referencing a serializer class before define in Django Rest-framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, syntax, django-rest-framework

```
# main.py

from rest_framework import serializers

class FirstSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    second = SecondSerializer(
        read_only=True)

class SecondSerializer(serializers.ModelSerialzier):
    # ...
```

How can I make this possible?

I mean, lift the declaration of a class before it was defined, is that possible? How?

#### Reason

In fact, I'm developing on django-rest-framework.

Seeing this section: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

I want to embed one Serializer in another, but the Serializer Class must be defined later.

So how to make this work?

Comment: I'd be more worried about having a circular reference...

Comment: Likely [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @deceze - I suppose as long as they're class variables and not instance variables, it shouldn't explode.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I've edit the question, in fact a rest-framework case, please have look.

Comment: Do you mean the example with `TrackSerializer` and `AlbumSerializer`? `TrackSerializer` is defined first and does not include an `AlbumSerializer`, while `AlbumSerializer`, defined second, does include a `TrackSerializer`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yes, swap the class definition, an error occurred.

Answer (score 4):

a somehow hacky way would be to add the class variable after `B` has been defined:

```
class A:
    pass

class B:
    a = A()

A.b = B()
```

...the dynamic nature of python classes allows you to do that.

Comment: Too ugly.. Is there any other way?

Comment: I dont see any other alternative to do that. Either define the second serializer before using it or this.

Comment: This was the first pattern I tried, and it didn't work. I think DRF does some magic when the class is first declared, and adding a class variable later doesn't trigger the magic. What happened when I tried this was that B.a used the A serializer, but A.b was serialized using DRF's automatically-generated serialization of the B model, completely ignoring the B serializer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

```py
class Post:
    def __init__(self, *, title, reply_to=None):
        self.title = title
        self.reply_to = reply_to

class PostSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title       = serializers.CharField()

PostSerializer._declared_fields['reply_to'] = PostSerializer()

p0 = Post(title="p0")
p1 = Post(title="p1", reply_to=p0)

serializer = PostSerializer(p1)
print(serializer.data)
```

And I got

```
{'title': 'p1', 'reply_to': OrderedDict([('title', 'p0'), ('reply_to', None)])}
```

Comment: see also https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L288